# .net application size in memory

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-management

What are the ways to reduce the amount of memory my applications take in RAM?..Because even 30kb application loads ~20Mb of "unneeded" dlls.Am i mistaking when i think that any .NET app takes at least 10Mb in working set of memory when we need a form with text in it? Couldn't find any explanation of this :(

PS
question is closed. But i suggest everyone interested in how CLR works read this: [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this post](http://www.itwriting.com/dotnetmem.php) helpful.

Comment: Looks like, I do unterstand your questions ;-) Up to now, I gave the correct answers to all (2) your questions *g*

Comment: "it will be interesting to see how .NET 2.0 compares when it comes out of beta"  YOWCH!  Still pretty applicable, tho.

Comment: yes,Will :)) saw that..but this article had some explanations for me :) tho, i'll be really good if someone gives bit modern article of this type :) 
Peter, sorry for my english :(

Comment: It's amazing that this question still gets asked, 7 years after .NET's release.

Answer (score 3):

First .NET application launch takes a lot of memory to load a lot of .NET internal data, but all other launches of this application or another one would take a significantly less.

Comment: thanks for the answer :)..but doesnt that mean that if ive already lounched some .net app with the dlls my app uses-my one wont load them?(in practice task manager shows that is loads a lot of something :( )